# Pro-rated SaaS billing service

Tags: saas, billing

Can anyone advice a SaaS billing service that supports pro-rated billing?

I.e.:

1) Customer registers at 15th of the 1st month.
2) On 1st of 2nd month, customer get charged for the 15 days.
3) On 1st of the 3rd month, customer get charged for the whole 30 days of the previous month.

This in order to keep all billing consolidated in a single date.

I've checked some services, but so far they don't seem to provide such functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most SaaS billing services now support Pro rating. For example you could look into services such as [Recurly](http://recurly.com) or [Chargify](http://chargify.com).